# Ajax request fails from FB canvas but works on domain (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, codeigniter

I have the following problem. I have a working PHP/CodeIgniter app and I'm integrating it into Facebook now.

However, an AJAX POST request fails with error 400, and I see in the console that CodeIgniter throws an error saying `The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.`.

This is the URL: `https://domain-name.com/apps/main/go_to_game/id=453494284796333&redirect`

There are no special characters or anything.

What makes it more confusing:

1) the request works when I open the app on the domain directly (and not through FB)

2) a request to a similar URL works even when sent from FB. This is the URL: `https://domain-name.com/apps/main/get_user_stuff`/

This is the code that sends the request, pretty basic stuff:

```
$.post(base+"main/go_to_game/"+gid,function(resp){
    //handle response
});
```

Where `base` is `https://domain-name.com/apps/` and `gid` is an integer. Any ideas?

Comment: you need to check the config item `$config[permitted_uri_chars]`

Comment: @karanthakkar `$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';`

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out - it was the `&` that was disallowed (which is a bit ridiculous but not getting into that right now). Anyway, there was no `&redirect` in the URL when the request was not sent from Facebook, so that's why the problem only happened there.